# Open JSF page from a Servlet with login information

Tags: jsf, servlets

following BalusC guide I try to create a Login system in order to access to my JSF page through a Servlet but it doesn't work :(

My Servlet for Login is:

```
public class DoLogin  extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    creaLogin(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    creaLogin(request, response);
}

//This method call the FacesContext and pass login nformation
private void creaLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    FacesContext facesContext = FaceUtil.getFacesContext(request, response);

    //Retrieve login information from get/post callback
    String userid=request.getParameter("userid");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");

    //I create an istance of LoginBean backingbean that manage login information for my JSF page
    LoginBean mioBean = (LoginBean) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, 
            "#{loginBean}", LoginBean.class);
    mioBean.setUsername(userid);
    mioBean.setPassword(password);
    mioBean.externalLogin();   //this method perform all needed operation and intialize all backing beans of my app

    //Call ma xhtml page 
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav 
       = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) 
               facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    nav.performNavigation("pannello");

}
```

}

FaceUtil is the same showed by BalusC in his example.

thank you in advance

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not treat a servlet as a JSF backing bean. JSF is a MVC framework which is built on top of Servlet API. If replacing the servlet by a fullworthy JSF backing bean is not an option for some reason, You should just do exactly the same using "plain" Servlet API as JSF is doing under the covers of the `FacesContext`.

For example,

```
LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
request.getSession().setAttribute("loginBean", loginBean); // Puts bean in session scope.
loginBean.setUsername(userid);
loginBean.setPassword(password);
loginBean.externalLogin(); // Note: if this has CDI/EJB dependencies, just refactor and inject them in servlet instead.

response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/pannello.xhtml"); // Assuming FacesServlet is mapped on *.xhtml.
```